Is there a recursive identity for the derivative of the gamma function $\Gamma'(x)$
For the normal gamma we have:
$$\Gamma(x) = (x-1)\Gamma(x-1)$$
For the digamma we have:
$$\Psi(x) = \Psi(x-1) + \frac{1}{x-1}$$
Is there something similar for $\Gamma'(x) = f(x-1)$?

Well, the simple product rule says $$\Gamma'(x)=\Gamma(x-1)+(x-1)\Gamma'(x-1).$$ You probably can't do much better.

Sorry, i don't quite follow. How did you derive this? EDIT: I see what you mean, you just differentiated the recursive formula for gamma(x) on both sides.

The derivative of $f(x)g(x)$ is $f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x).$ Apply with $f(x)=x-1, g(x)=\Gamma(x).$ @terraregina

Yes, indeed, this recursion is really the digamma recursion. Just divide  my formula on the left side by $\Gamma(x)$ and the right side by $(x-1)\Gamma(x-1).$

You can post this is as an answer. I will accept it :) Thank you!
